# Jquery Countdown To Next Wednesday 11pm

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, countdowntimer

I need to write a function that will take a javascript date object in UTC time. It needs to find the difference in seconds from the given date and next (or coming) Wednesday 11pm then put it in a countdown object. Once the the timer hits 0, I need it to restart again. I know I have to use the getDay() function somehow but I'm unsure of how to go about this.

Comment: Where is the date object coming from? Server side to avoid possible incorrect time on client machine? Or do you just want to use client machine's time and convert to UTC? What do you mean by *countdown object*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Logic and Code

- You don't need jQuery for the countdown timer itself. The date object is part of plain vanilla JavaScript.
- For UTC, you'll want to use the [`getUTCDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay) method.
- Assuming `givenDate` is a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, the following would calculate how many days until the coming Wednesday (day 3).

  ```
  var daysUntilTarget = (3 - givenDate.getUTCDay() + 7) % 7;
  ```
- If given date is on a Wednesday, the above will return `0` and you'll need to determine if target time has passed yet. You could use something like this:

  ```
  var daysUntilTarget,
      targetDay = 3,
      targetHour = 23,
      targetMinute = 0,
      targetSecond = 0;

  if (
      targetDay == givenDate.getUTCDay() &&
      targetHour * 3600 +
      targetMinute * 60 +
      targetSecond * 1 <
      givenDate.getUTCHours() * 3600 +
      givenDate.getUTCMinutes() * 60 +
      givenDate.getUTCSeconds() * 1 +
      givenDate.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1000
  ) {
      //given date is after target time on target day 
      daysUntilTarget = 7;
  }
  ```
- Use the [`setUTCDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate) and [`setUTCHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours) methods to set the target date and time.

  ```
  var targetDate = new Date(givenDate);
  targetDate.setUTCDate(givenDate.getUTCDate() + daysUntilTarget);
  targetDate.setUTCHours(targetHour, targetMinute, targetSecond);
  ```
- Use the [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method to get a timestamp for both the given date and the target date. Then you can calculate the difference between these and divide by 1000 to get the number of seconds.

  ```
  var countdownSeconds = (targetDate.getTime() - givenDate.getTime()) / 1000;
  ```
- The following will convert the total seconds into days, minutes, and seconds. You can then write these to an element in your HTML.

  ```
  var daysLeft, hoursLeft, minutesLeft, secondsLeft;

  secondsLeft = parseInt(countdownSeconds);

  daysLeft = parseInt(secondsLeft / 86400);
  secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 86400;

  hoursLeft = parseInt(secondsLeft / 3600);
  secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 3600;

  minutesLeft = parseInt(secondsLeft / 60);
  secondsLeft = parseInt(secondsLeft % 60);
  ```
- Be sure to convert `countdownSeconds` to an integer before doing further calculations with it. Otherwise, you may get undesired results due to floating point math. For example,

  ```
  0.009 / 86400 = 1.0416666666666665e-7;
  parseInt(1.0416666666666665e-7) = 1;
  parseInt(0.009 / 86400) = 1; //probably not what you were expecting
  ```

### Countdown Timer

To update the timer, you could decrement a counter or use the client machine's clock to keep time.

- The counter method is not as accurate as the clock method because the former doesn't take into account the amount of time it takes for the code to run. I've noticed a 3-second loss over a half-hour period. Adjusting the loop interval will not fix this since different browsers run code at different speeds. And code may run slower for other reasons such as when machine is low on memory.
- The client machine's time may not be accurate to begin with. However, the server time can be compared to the client time initially to calculate an offset. Then the client time can be used as a counter rather than an absolute value. The draw back is that if the client time changes, it will affect the countdown. Note that time zone changes and changes due to Daylight Saving Time will not affect the countdown since they do not affect the timestamp.

### Examples

I've created two fiddles using the code described above.

- [Countdown Timer (Using Counter)](http://jsfiddle.net/toxalot/R3c8s/)
- [Countdown Timer (Using Clock)](http://jsfiddle.net/toxalot/qz2VU/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't upvote you because I don't have enough reputation but you helped a lot.